# Autotask REST API & Power Query Projects Entity

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Trying to get my head around this API and having looked around i'm struggling to get the syntax of calls.

I'm simpley trying to make a call to list all projects which I think I need to identify a filter as part of the call. From that call I would filter through the data to present a view and or work with it in Power BI.

Can some one assist with helping me understand how to form that URL/feilds ?

I've included the PowerQuery code I am using as it may be helpful for others butif any one can help with suggsted edits I would be appriciated.

https://www.autotask.net/help/developerhelp/Content/APIs/REST/Entities/ProjectsEntity.htm

https://www.autotask.net/help/developerhelp/Content/APIs/REST/API_Calls/REST_Basic_Query_Calls.htm#GET%C2%A0with

```
let

    url = "https://webservices4.autotask.net/atservicesrest/v1.0/Projects/",
    GetJsonQuery = Web.Contents(url,
        [
            Headers = [
                #"UserName"="xxxxxx",
                #"Secret"="xxxxxxx",
                #"ApiIntegrationCode"="xxxxxxxx",
                #"Content-Type"="application/json"
            ]
        ]
    ),
    FormatAsJsonQuery = Json.Document(GetJsonQuery)
in
    FormatAsJsonQuery
```

Powerquery is failing on ""IncludeFields"" saying "Expression.SyntaxError: Token ',' expected."

```
let
    url = "https://webservices4.autotask.net/atservicesrest/v1.0/Projects/query?search={"IncludeFields": ["Id", "isactive","projectName", "projectNumber", "status", "opportunityID" ,]}",
    GetJsonQuery = Web.Contents(url,
        [
            Headers = [
                #"UserName"="xxxxx",
                #"Secret"="xxxxxx",
                #"ApiIntegrationCode"="xxxxxxxx",
                #"Content-Type"="application/json"
            ]
        ]
    ),
    FormatAsJsonQuery = Json.Document(GetJsonQuery)
in
    FormatAsJsonQuery
```

Updated Code -

```
 let
// NB Making calls to multiple instances from the same Power BI Dash can cause problems with authentication

    // Common parameters
    queryStringApiIntegrationCodevar = "xxxxxx",
    queryStringUserNamevar = "xxxxxx",
    queryStringUserSecretvar = "xxxxxx",
    queryStringContentTypevar = "application/json",
    headers = [#"ApiIntegrationCode"=queryStringApiIntegrationCodevar, #"UserName"=queryStringUserNamevar, #"Secret"=queryStringUserSecretvar, #"Content-Type"=queryStringContentTypevar],
    apiUrl = "https://webservices4.autotask.net/ATServicesRest/V1.0/Projects/query",
    apiUrlnew = "https://webservices4.autotask.net/ATServicesRest/V1.0/Projects/query/next",
    searchFilter = "{""filter"":[{""op"":""gte"",""field"":""id"",""value"":""0""}]}",           


//initReq = Json.Document(Web.Contents(apiUrl, headers)),
initReq = try Json.Document(Web.Contents(apiUrl, [Headers=headers, Query=[search=searchFilter]])) otherwise error "Failed to retrieve data from the API 1st Pass",
//initReq = try Json.Document(Web.Contents(apiUrl, headers)) otherwise error apiUrl,

initData = initReq[items],
    //We want to get data = {lastNPagesData, thisPageData}, where each list has the limit # of Records, 
    //then we can List.Combine() the two lists on each iteration to aggregate all the records. We can then
    //create a table from those records
    gather = (data as list, uri) =>
        let
            //build new uri
            // newUri = Json.Document(Web.Contents(uri, headersgatherfunc))[pageDetails][nextPageUrl],
            newUri = try Json.Document(Web.Contents(uri, [Headers=headers, Query=[search=searchFilter]]))[pageDetails][nextPageUrl] otherwise error "Failed to retrieve data from the API 2nd Pass",
            //get new req & data
            newReq = try Json.Document(Web.Contents(newUri, [Headers=headers, Query=[search=searchFilter]])) otherwise error "Failed to retrieve data from the API 3rd Pass",
            newdata = newReq[items],
            //add that data to rolling aggregate
            data = List.Combine({data, newdata}),
            //if theres no next page of data, return. if there is, call @gather again to get more data
            check = if newReq[pageDetails][nextPageUrl] = null then data else @gather(data, newUri)
        in check,
    //before we call gather(), we want see if its even necesarry. First request returns only one page? Return.
    //outputList = try if initReq[pageDetails][nextPageUrl] = null then initData else gather(initData, BaseURI)otherwise error uri,
    outputList = try if initReq[pageDetails][nextPageUrl] = null then initData else gather(initData, apiUrl)otherwise error "Failed outputList",
    //then place records into a table. This will expand all columns available in the record.
    expand = Table.FromRecords(outputList)
in
    expand
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any one intrested (as this was not as easy as it looked) this is the completed code.

Note for any one following [Feilds] need to be updated to reflect the api you are using to work. This one is for Autotask from Datto

```
    // https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Query/Handling-a-Paginated-API-with-Prebuilt-Next-Page-URI-in-Response/m-p/1777718#M53393 - Refrence page

let

searchFilter = "{""filter"":[{""id"":""gte"",""value"":""0""}]}",
searchParam = Uri.EscapeDataString(searchFilter),
headers = [Headers = [
                #"ApiIntegrationCode"="xxxxxx",
                #"UserName"="xxxxxx",
                #"Secret"="xxxxxx",
                #"Content-Type"="application/json"]],
baseuri = "https://webservices4.autotask.net/ATServicesRest/V1.0/Projects/query?search=" & searchParam,

initReq = Json.Document(Web.Contents(baseuri, headers)),

initData = initReq[items],

//We want to get data = {lastNPagesData, thisPageData}, where each list has the limit # of Records,

//then we can List.Combine() the two lists on each iteration to aggregate all the records. We can then

//create a table from those records

gather = (data as record, uri) =>

let
//get new offset from active uri
newOffset = Json.Document(Web.Contents(uri, headers))[count][prevPageUrl][nextPageUrl],

//build new uri using the original uri so we dont append offsests
newUri = baseuri & "&count=" & newOffset,

//get new req & data
newReq = Json.Document(Web.Contents(newUri, headers)) ,
newdata = newReq[items] ,

//add that data to rolling aggregate
data = List.Combine({data, newdata}),

//if theres no next page of data, return. if there is, call @gather again to get more data

check = if Table.Contains ( Record.ToTable(newReq) , [Name = "count"] ) = true then @gather (data , newUri) else data

in check,

//before we call gather(), we want see if its even necesarry. First request returns only one page? Return.
outputList = if Table.Contains ( Record.ToTable (initReq) , [Name = "count"] ) = true then gather( initData , baseuri) else initData ,

//then place records into a table. This will expand all columns available in the record.
expand = Table.FromRecords(outputList)

in 

expand
```

Thanks

Terran

EDIT - Update

```
let

// {"filter":[{"id":"gte","value":"0"}]}

// searchFilter = "{""filter"":[{""id"":""gte"",""value"":""0""}]}",
// {"filter":[{"op":"gte","field":"id","value":"0"}]}
searchFilter = "{""filter"":[{""op"":""gte"",""field"":""id"",""value"":""0""}]}",
// searchParam = Uri.EscapeDataString(searchFilter),

//baseuri = "https://webservices16.autotask.net/ATServicesRest/V1.0/Projects/" & searchParam,
apiUrl = "https://webservices16.autotask.net/ATServicesRest/V1.0/Roles/query",
apiUrlnew = "https://webservices16.autotask.net/atservicesrest/V1.0/Roles/query/next",

queryStringApiIntegrationCodevar = "KEY",
queryStringUserNamevar = "EMAIL",
queryStringUserSecretvar = "PW",
queryStringContentTypevar = "application/json",
queryStringnew = "",

// NB Making calls to multiple instances from the same Power BI Dash can cause problems with authentication

headers = [Headers = [
                #"ApiIntegrationCode"=queryStringApiIntegrationCodevar,
                #"UserName"=queryStringUserNamevar,
                #"Secret"=queryStringUserSecretvar,
                #"Content-Type"=queryStringContentTypevar],
                Query = [search = searchFilter]
                ],

//initReq = Json.Document(Web.Contents(apiUrl, headers)),
initReq = try Json.Document(Web.Contents(apiUrl, headers)) otherwise error "Failed to retrieve data from the API 1st Pass",
//initReq = try Json.Document(Web.Contents(apiUrl, headers)) otherwise error apiUrl,

initData = initReq[items],
    //We want to get data = {lastNPagesData, thisPageData}, where each list has the limit # of Records, 
    //then we can List.Combine() the two lists on each iteration to aggregate all the records. We can then
    //create a table from those records
    gather = (data as list, uri) =>
        let
            //build new uri 
            newUri = try Json.Document(Web.Contents(uri, headers))[pageDetails][nextPageUrl] otherwise error "Failed to retrieve data from the API 2nd Pass",
            //get new req & data
            newReq = try Json.Document(Web.Contents(newUri, headers)) otherwise error "Failed to retrieve data from the API 3rd Pass",
            newdata = newReq[items],
            //add that data to rolling aggregate
            data = List.Combine({data, newdata}),
            //if theres no next page of data, return. if there is, call @gather again to get more data
            check = if newReq[pageDetails][nextPageUrl] = null then data else @gather(data, newUri)
        in check,
    //before we call gather(), we want see if its even necesarry. First request returns only one page? Return.
    //outputList = try if initReq[pageDetails][nextPageUrl] = null then initData else gather(initData, BaseURI)otherwise error uri,
    outputList = try if initReq[pageDetails][nextPageUrl] = null then initData else gather(initData, apiUrl)otherwise error "Failed outputList",
    //then place records into a table. This will expand all columns available in the record.
    expand = Table.FromRecords(outputList),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(expand,{{"id", Order.Descending}})
in
    #"Sorted Rows"
```